# How can a multi-property ndb query be successful without a composite index?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have this entity model:

```
class ApartCILabel(ndb.Model):
    project_id = ndb.IntegerProperty(indexed=True)
    changeset_ids = ndb.IntegerProperty(repeated=True, indexed=True)   # ApartCIChangeset IDs
    # other properties
```

I recently added a new type of query for these entities:

```
            keys = ApartCILabel.query(ApartCILabel.project_id == self.db_data.project_id,
                                      ApartCILabel.changeset_ids == self.key_id).fetch(keys_only=True)
            if keys:
                label = Label(db_key=keys[0], handler=self.handler)
                logging.debug('label found: %s' % label.name)
            else:
                logging.error('label for %s not found' % self.lid)
```

I knew I needed a composite index for it, so I ran the app in `dev_appserver.py`, which used to automatically update my `index.yaml` file. I see the debug message in the log, indicating that the query was successful:

```
DEBUG    2018-02-20 23:56:11,720 ci_changeset.py:70] label found: ACI_COPY_OF_SMALL_180221_1
```

To my surprise, I see no update in my `index.yaml` file. OK, I did update my GAE SDK since the last time I needed an index update (running `1.9.65` now), maybe the symlink-based scheme I'm using for sharing my index definition file across all my services interferes somehow. No problem, I'm gonna deploy the change on GAE and I'll see the missing composite index error there.

Again surprise: the query is successful, no error.

I checked my `index.yaml` file, the only composite index for this kind is this one:

```
- kind: ApartCILabel
  properties:
  - name: project_id
  - name: created
    direction: desc
```

I double-checked the datastore indexes in the developer console, which is, as I expected, in sync with the `index.yaml` file:

[image]

I even performed a manual query in the developer console, which should also require a composite index. Also successful:

[image]

How is it possible for such query to function without a composite index? What am I missing?

UPDATE:

After a few hours I performed another similar manual query, again the result is correct, but this time the `Your Datastore does not have the composite index (developer-supplied) required for this query.` error (or should I rather call it warning?) showed up:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Queries using only equality filters do not require a composite index to be created.  From the documentation:

> Cloud Datastore provides *built-in*, or automatic, indexes for queries of the following forms:
>
> - Queries using only ancestor and equality filters

https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/indexes#index_configuration

Comment: OK, I missed this (actually I somehow thought of it as only one property filter per query). Probably the right answer. But then why does the error in the snapshot shown in the question update pops up? ;)

Comment: Yes, I get how it works now. This article also helped (including inequality filters!): https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/indexselection#Improved_Query_Planner