# Google App Engine Datastore - query with StructuredProperty in projection and filter

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have a couple ndb models looks like these:

```
class Product(ndb.Model):
    manufacturer = ndb.StringProperty()
    category = ndb.StringProperty()
    price = ndb.FloatProperty()
class Customer(ndb.Model):
    customerId = ndb.StringProperty()
    name = ndb.StringProperty()    
    products = ndb.StructuredProperty(Product, repeated=True)
```

And I'd like to query based on 'manufacturer' and 'category' of the product he/she owns. So this query works as expected.

```
query = Customer.query(Customer.products == Product(manufacturer=data_json["product"]["manufacturer"],
                                                    category=data_json["product"]["category"]))

results= query.fetch()
```

However, I cannot get the "projection" to work along with this query. The following query simply returned nothing.

```
query = Customer.query(Customer.products == Product(manufacturer=data_json["product"]["manufacturer"],
                                                    category=data_json["product"]["category"]))

results= query.fetch(projection=[Customer.products.price])
```

But if I use the projection without the filter, the projection part works fine. The following query will return all entities but only the 'price' property

```
results= Customer.query().fetch(projection=[Customer.products.price])
```

Any thoughts? Thanks.

BTW, my queries were developed based on this article.
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/queries#filtering_structured_properties

Comment: Do you have a composite index for such query? It *might* not always be needed, being an equality-only filter, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48896357/how-can-a-multi-property-ndb-query-be-successful-without-a-composite-index. But from what I read in the article mentioned in the comments I suspect sometimes it *might* not work without one. To force a complaint about the index and maybe get a very close index definition add temporarily an ordering of the results. Then modify the definition to remove the `direction:` in it (and the result ordering).

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for the feedback. I do have composite index by checking the index.yaml. Maybe I missed something, but I am curious why would the index matters in this case? The query without the projection was able to return the expected results with equality filter, but just not with project. Thank you.

Comment: Never mind then - if you have the index my theory doesn't apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way of combining **AND** and **OR** operations in the *ndb* library is documented in [NDB Client Library's documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/queries#nest_and_or).

With the query below, you are performing an AND operation in the filter, so instead of this one, you should use the one I propose below, using *ndb.AND()*.

```
# Your query
query = Customer.query(Customer.products == Product(manufacturer=data_json["product"]["manufacturer"], category=data_json["product"]["category"]))

# Query using ndb.AND
query = Customer.query(ndb.AND(Customer.products == Product(manufacturer=data_json["product"]["manufacturer"]), Customer.products == Product(category=data_json["product"]["category"])))
```

Also, it turns out that if you perform the [filtering in multiple steps](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/queries#filter_by_prop), the query also works:

```
# Your request
query = Customer.query(Customer.products == Product(manufacturer=data_json["product"]["manufacturer"], category=data_json["product"]["category"]))
results = query.fetch(projection=[Customer.products.price])

# Request performing filter in multiple steps
query = Customer.query(Customer.products == Product(category=data_json["product"]["category"]))
query1 = query.filter(Customer.products == Product(manufacturer=data_json["product"]["manufacturer"]))
results = query1.fetch(projection=[Customer.products.price])
```

You can use either of the proposed alternatives, although I would suggest using *ndb.AND()* as it minimizes the code and is also the best way to combine AND operations.

---

***UPDATE*** with some code:

*app.yaml*

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: main.app
```

*main.py*

```
import webapp2
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

# Datastore Models
class Product(ndb.Model):
    manufacturer = ndb.StringProperty()
    category = ndb.StringProperty()
    price = ndb.FloatProperty()

class Customer(ndb.Model):
    customerId = ndb.StringProperty()
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    products = ndb.StructuredProperty(Product, repeated=True)

# Create entities for testing purposes
class CreateEntities(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        prod1 = Product(manufacturer="Google", category="GCP", price=105.55)
        prod2 = Product(manufacturer="Google", category="GCP", price=123.45)
        prod3 = Product(manufacturer="Google", category="Drive", price=10.38)
        prod1.put()
        prod2.put()
        prod3.put()

        cust1 = Customer(customerId="Customer1", name="Someone", products=[prod1,prod2,prod3])
        cust2 = Customer(customerId="Customer2", name="Someone else", products=[prod1])
        cust3 = Customer(customerId="Customer3", name="Noone", products=[prod3])
        cust1.put()
        cust2.put()
        cust3.put()

        # Response text
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write('Done creating entities')

class GetEntities(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        # This will not work
        #query = Customer.query(Customer.products == Product(category="GCP", manufacturer="Google"))
        #results = query.fetch(projection=[Customer.products.price])

        # Alternative 1 - WORKS
        #query = Customer.query(Customer.products == Product(category="GCP"))
        #query1 = query.filter(Customer.products == Product(manufacturer="Google"))
        #results = query1.fetch(projection=[Customer.products.price])

        # Alternative 2 - WORKS
        query = Customer.query(ndb.AND(Customer.products == Product(manufacturer="Google"), Customer.products == Product(category="GCP")))
        results = query.fetch(projection=[Customer.products.price])

        self.response.out.write('<html><body>')
        for result in results:
            self.response.out.write("%s<br><br>" % result)
        self.response.out.write('</body></html>')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/createEntities', CreateEntities),
    ('/getEntities', GetEntities),
], debug=True)
```

Comment: Hi desto, thanks for the post. I agreed that ndb.AND() would make it more clear in terms of the query's filter condition. These 3 different queries generate the same results. However, the issue is nothing was found as soon as the projection is used. I tried the projection with all three different queries but none worked.

Comment: I'm surprised that did not work for you. I reproduced your same issue and solved it by changing the way the filters were made. Are you running the code in the Development Server or in production GAE? The dev server creates indexes automatically for you, so it may be a better option for testing. Also, I updated my answer with a snippet of the code I am using, so that you can compare. As I see it, the only difference between your code and mine is that you are reading data from a JSON, and mine is hard-coded, but that should not affect, given that your filters work if there's no projection.

Comment: Hi dsesto, you were right. I did another test and verified the suggestion works as expected. I am able to use projection by breaking each condition into a individual filter (like Alternative 1 mentioned in your code.) The reason why it didn't work for me last time was I had multiple attributes in the Product in query filter. -> query.filter(Customer.products == Product(category='A',manufacturer='Nike'))
By breaking them into two filters works. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem, @James , I am glad I could help!