# Google Cloud Datastore Indexes for count queries

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

Google cloud datastore mandates that there needs to be composite indexes built to query on multiple fields of one kind. Taking the following query for example,

```
class Greeting(ndb.Model):
    user = ndb.StringProperty()
    place = ndb.StringProperty()

# Query 1
Greeting.query(Greeting.user == 'yash@gmail.com', Greeting.place == 'London').fetch()
# Query 2
Greeting.query(Greeting.user == 'yash@gmail.com', Greeting.place == 'London').count()
```

I am using python with ndb to access cloud datastore. In the above example, Query 1 raises `NeedIndexError` if there is no composite index defined on `user` and `place`. But Query 2 works fine even if there is no index on `user` and `place`.

I would like to understand how cloud datastore fetches the count (Query 2) without the index when it mandates the index for fetching the list of entities (Query 1). I understand it stores Stats per kind per index which would result in quicker response for counts on existing indexes (Refer [docs](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/stats)). But I'm unable to explain the above behaviour.

Note: There is no issue when querying on one property of a given kind as cloud datastore has indexes on a single properties by default.

Comment: Maybe relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48896357/how-can-a-multi-property-ndb-query-be-successful-without-a-composite-index/48912200#48912200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no clear & direct explanation on why this happens but most likely its because how improved query planner works with `zigzag` indexes.

You can read more about this here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/indexselection#Improved_Query_Planner

The logic behind `count()` working and `fetch()` does not probably because with `count()` you don't need to keep in memory a lot of results.

So in case of `count()` you can easily scale by splitting work in multiple chunks processed in parallel and then just sum corresponding counts into one. You can't do this cheaply with cursors/recordsets.

Comment: Does that mean if I add an index on the fields in count query explicitly, it won't improve the performance? I'm just curious to understand if not having an index will degrade the query performance.

Comment: Adding an index would improve your read performance and probably would make it cheaper to run queries - though you would need to run a test to confirm it. Though adding an index would increase your write & storage costs.

Comment: I found an interesting thing after I posted the question. I have 3 indexes on different combinations of fields. But I didn't have the index on the combination upon which I'm running count query. Interestingly, not all combinations of fields for count query work. Some of them do fail with `NeedIndexError`. Your speculation about `zigzag` indexes might be right after all. Taking that into account, you are right about the read performance as well. Perhaps google would be better off explicitly stating about the `zigzag` index usage in order to avoid confusion.